# How to stop the keyring dialoug when opening Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, seahorse

I've been searching in a lot of answers for this question but so far no answer solved it for me.
I've an account for my kids on my Ubuntu 14.04 PC. This account have no password and is set to login automatically.
On this account when I open Google Chrome from launcher, it opens a window to ask for keyring password for Default account. Leaving this password to blank didn't work.
I tried to open seahorse and unlock the Default keyring or change the password but I don't know what is the original password.
I tried to create another keyring in the seahorse app but now the Chrome when opens it asks for unlocking both the new keyring and the Default.
Is there any solution to stop this window?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this window emerge only when I kept logged in my google acount, but today I succeeded stoping this window to appear doing the following steps that I have not seen in any forum:

1. Open Chrome
2. Enter the password and press "unlock"
3. Open "Seahorse" by searching it in the Unity Launcher
4. Right click in "Login"
5. Select "Lock"
6. Restart your PC and try it !!

I hope this solution help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For me(Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS),

Show Applications > Passwords and Keys > Unlock Default keyring > Property on Chrome Safe Storage & Chrome Safe Storage Control > Erase Password to blank

resolved the issue. This resolution stays regardless of Chrome updates.
[image: Passwords and Keys]